# Mercurial post-build commit in MPLAB (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, version-control, mercurial, mplab

I have a question about using Mercurial with MPLAB (which is basically just a wrapper around Eclipse).

I am wondering if it is possible to add a post-build step to commit a project to the repo.

Right now, we're just doing it the brute force way; we've taken the "commit often" part to the extreme.  My co-worker has setup a Windows Event to execute every 15 mins that runs a script he wrote to commit everything in our working directory to the repo.  This is great for making sure you don't miss anything (when his computer is on), but has the downside of committing broken code a lot of the time.

I can't help but think that there has to be a more streamlined way to handle our commits.  I've read multiple tutorials/wikis about Hg but nothing goes this specific; everything stays much more "general overview".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building via `make` then just add your commit script as the last stage, (after elf generation), in your makefile.  For managed builds see [here](http://eclipsebook.in/c-cpp-development/building-code/build-eclipse-managed/#img-eb-c-cpp-build-steps) - assuming it is available in that version and again run your existing script.  Either will result in a commit on a successful build.

Comment: Does the "post-build action" only run after a successfull build?

i.e. if there is an build error I don't want it to commit the broken code.

Comment: I believe so but you can easily test it by adding a harmless but visible post build action and then doing a broken build deliberately.

Comment: BTW the standard make rule, unless overridden, is stop on first operation that results in one or more errors.